# access to the count() function in laravel

Tags: laravel, count, laravel-4, eloquent

I've been following a tutorial which has shown me that i can pass the details of all records in a database table to a view like this:

```
$teams = $this->team->all();
```

In the view there is a section of code that says...

```
@if ($teams->count())
```

and this is fine... if there are $teams then do the next bit.

The problem comes when I want to refine my query to this (i am passing $id into the controller):

```
$teams = DB::table('teams')->where('league_id', $id)->get();
```

Simply, when done this way, the count() function in the view is no longer available. 
I have done print_r($teams) on both the resulting $teams arrays and the first one has so much more information available in it, but I was wondering if anyone can help me understand why count() ins't available and how i can 'reinstate it'?

Many thanks.
DS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you'er not using Eloquent by the look of that query, that you're using the native query builder.

So, if you're planning on using Eloquent, assuming you have a `Team` model, something like this:

```
$teams = Team::where('league_id', $id)->get();
```

This will return an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` (a subclass of `Illuminate\Support\Collection`). This is where you can use `$teams->count()`.

However, the query builder you're using there is returning an array of `stdClass` objects.

So, you can either treat it as an array, or in the place where you retrieve teams, you can simple add a new line:

```
$teams = new Illuminate\Support\Collection($teams);
```

And you're back in business.

Comment: $teams = Team::where....

this is exactly the bit I was hoping to find. Thanks so much. DS